# As adjectives, not in math: 'different' vs 'differential'

Tags: discussion

Why was [As adjectives, not in math: 'different' vs 'differential'](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/20789/14) migrated uni-laterally?

An average Anglophone with no medical background wouldn't understand the context and so can't answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

It was migrated because it's off topic. Subject matter knowledge isn't necessary to understand and answer the question.

Comment: 1. "Subject matter knowledge isn't necessary to understand and answer the question." This doesn't answer my post where I wrote "An average Anglophone with no medical background wouldn't understand the context and so can't answer my question."

Comment: 2. Even if you're right, why not let the community decide rather than a unilateral closure?

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal 1. And yet your question has [an answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/522375/74256). 2. Because the question was off topic on MedSci.

Comment: '2. Because the question was off topic on MedSci.' Isn't this circular reasoning?

Comment: @Greek-Area51Proposal you asserting that that people without medical background wouldn't be able to answer doesn't make it true. The word 'differential' and its variations are being used with their standard English meanings. A standard English dictionary is sufficient to answer your question, medical knowledge is not required.